# Ruby Convert String to File

Tags: ruby, string, file

Is it possible to convert a string to a file without writing it to disk?

I would like to work ubiquitously with either a string of a file:

```
input = "123"
if (ARGV.length == 1)
   input = File.open(ARGV[0])

   #do stuff with input
end
```

Can I create a file from a string (without writing to disk)? Otherwise, I would not be able to do `input.readline()` when it's a string.

Comment: please add end keyword at the end of your example ;)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `StringIO` ([1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html), [1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html)) to create an `IO` ([1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/IO.html), [1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html)) object (that is, an object that acts like a file) out of a string:

```
file = StringIO.new("123")
line = file.readline
file.close
```

Answer (score 5):

`StringIO` can be used to give a file-like interface to strings.

Answer (score 2):

The StringIO is nice, you could also do this using a block:

```
StringIO.open(string) do |file|
  # do stuff here
end
```

I like this alt over `file.close`